# Sidebar Menu for macOS in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to implement a menu, so far this is what have:

[image]

**NavigationView**

```
struct macOS_NavigationView: View {
    
    @State private var selectedTab: HostingBarCategories = .Screen1
    
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            // SideBar Menu
            List {
                ForEach(1 ... 10, id: \.self) { index in
                    NavigationLink(destination:
                                    Text("\(index)")
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    ) {
                        Text("Link \(index)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            
            // Primary View
            Text("Select a menu...")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

The part where I'm stuck is trying to implement my current model that I'm using for iOS in the TabBar:

**HostingBarCategories**

```
enum HostingBarCategories: Hashable {
    case Screen1
    case Screen2
    case Screen3
    case Screen4
    case Screen5
}
```

So how can I use that model so when a user clicks a menu it goes to that screen? (the model can be expanded, it doesn't have to be that one specifically)

Edit: Let me add the current iOS TabBar so it's more visually understandable, this is just for reference for the above and has nothing to do with the question:

```
struct iOS_TabBarView: View {
    
    @State private var selectedTab: HostingBarCategories = .Screen1
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            Text("1")
                .tag(0)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "pencil.and.outline")
                    Text("1")
                }
            Text("2")
                .tag(1)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                    Text("2")
                }
            Text("3")
                .tag(2)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "calendar.circle.fill")
                    Text("3")
                }
            Text("4")
                .tag(3)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "flame")
                    Text("4")
                }
            Text("5")
                .tag(3)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "slider.horizontal.3")
                    Text("5")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"how can I use that model so when a user clicks a menu it goes to that screen?"* - I didn't get this part. What screen? How this new screen is related with `HostingBarCategories`, ie. what should be the relation between `HostingBarCategories` and your view?

Comment: @pawello2222 the enums are the screens (different views) and are used to identify where the user wants to go. If you see in the iOS TabBar, when I click for example the first tab (0), it would be `.tag(0)` which represents the enum: `Screen1`. Does that make sence or I confused you more? The whole point is to use a model to build a menu (sidebar) for macOS

Comment: I'm wondering what should happen if I click some `link`. Is your question about updating the `selectedTab` when you click on any link?

Comment: @pawello2222 when you click one of the links in the Sidebar from the screenshot it would take you wherever you want, that's not the issue/question. Ok, let's put it this way, how would you implement a simple Sidebar for macOS with a model in place that can be reuse (the model) for the TabBar of the iOS app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your enum case-iterable to use it as model in `ForEach`, like

```
enum HostingBarCategories: Hashable, CaseIterable {
    case Screen1
    case Screen2
    case Screen3
    case Screen4
    case Screen5
    
    var string: String { String(describing: self) }
}

struct macOS_NavigationView: View {
    
    @State private var selectedTab: HostingBarCategories = .Screen1
    
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            // SideBar Menu
            List {
                ForEach(HostingBarCategories.allCases, id: \.self) { screen in
                    NavigationLink(destination:
                                    Text(screen.string)
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    ) {
                        Text("Link \(screen.string)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            
            // Primary View
            Text("Select a menu...")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Asperi, you've saved me so many times haha. What's the meaning of: `var string: String { String(describing: self) }` and also how would I describe in the model for example names for the Sidebar links so I can just change it on the model once and it changes everywhere. I'm trying to learn the right reusable way. The same applies to the icons I guess.

Comment: It is just a helper for demo to show enum case in Text, you can ignore it.

Comment: Nice and simple, this also still works in macOS 10.15, which I have to support.

Comment: Does `selectedTab`do anything in the example?