# TabBar with cases instead of int - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to reuse some old code from a question [I had previously asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65570665/sidebar-menu-for-macos-in-swiftui) and it's not working anymore, did something happen under the hood?

When I lunch the app the TabBar goes to index 0 instead of 2. This is my current code:

```
struct iOS_TabBarView: View {
    
    @State private var selectedTab: HostingBarCategories = .Screen3
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            Text("1")
                .tag(0)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "pencil.and.outline")
                    Text("1")
                }
            Text("2")
                .tag(1)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                    Text("2")
                }
            Text("3")
                .tag(2)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "calendar.circle.fill")
                    Text("3")
                }
            Text("4")
                .tag(3)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "flame")
                    Text("4")
                }
            Text("5")
                .tag(3)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "slider.horizontal.3")
                    Text("5")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

and the HostingBarCategories:

```
enum HostingBarCategories: Hashable, CaseIterable {
    case Screen1
    case Screen2
    case Screen3
    case Screen4
    case Screen5
    
    var string: String { String(describing: self) }
}
```

What's going on?

Comment: Is it iOS ro macOS issue now?

Comment: I'm working with iOS right now @Asperi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume tag & selection should be the same type, so try

```
struct iOS_TabBarView: View {
    
    @State private var selectedTab: HostingBarCategories = .Screen3
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            Text("1")
                .tag(HostingBarCategories.Screen1)    // << like this for all !!
```